# Angular manipulate service value inside test

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, ts-mockito

I'm trying to manipulate the service return value in my test and attach that value to components field.

So I mock `myService` inside the `Test1` and manipulate its value as `true` so that it always returns `true`. With the call `fixture.detectChanges();` I invoke the `this.myService.getProperty('param');` inside the `PageComponent` which should return `true` and make the value of `myField` also `true`. But it doesn't. The value of the field is still `false`. `Test1` fails ofcourse.

I don't undestand what happens. Why can I just define the return value `true` inside the test and make the components value by that?

**Test**

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { anything, instance, mock, reset, verify, when } from 'ts-mockito';
import { MyService } from '../services/myservice.service';

describe('Test', () => {
    let component: PageComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<PageComponent>;
    let myServiceMock: myService = mock(MyService);

    describe('PageComponent', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                imports: [],
                declarations: [PageComponent],
                schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
                providers: [
                    { provide: myService, useValue: instance(myServiceMock) },
                ]
            }).compileComponents();

            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PageComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
            fixture.detectChanges();
        });

        afterEach(() => {
            reset(myServiceMock);
        });

        it('Test1 - property should be true', () => {
            when(myServiceMock.getProperty(anything())).thenReturn(true);
            fixture.detectChanges();
            verify(myServiceMock.getProperty(anything())).once();
            expect(component.isCountryInfoVisible).toBeTrue();
            // Test Failed
            // Expected value to be true:
            //  true
            // Received:
            //  false
        });
    });
});
```

**PageComponent**

```
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {
    myField: boolean;

    constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.myField = this.myService.getProperty('param');
    }
}
```

**MyService**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    private properties: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>();

    constructor() { }

    public getProperty(key: string): string {
        return this.properties.get(key);
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: ngOnInit is already called on first detectChanges, the mock doesn't affect it.

Comment: @EstusFlask So, do I need to call `when` statement before the first `detectChanges` ?

Comment: Yes, I expect that you do.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @EstusFlask I've figured out what happens;

My service call is inside `ngOnInit` which gets already invoked by the first `fixture.detectChanges();`. In that case the second `fixture.detectChanges();` doesn't have any effect at all because it never get invoked again.

Solution:
move the `when(myServiceMock.getProperty(anything())).thenReturn(true);` just above the first `fixture.detectChanges();` like:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PageComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;

when(myServiceMock.getProperty(anything())).thenReturn(true);

fixture.detectChanges();
```